# Read dted with gdal in c++

Tags: gdal, dted

I need to find the elevation of lat and long point using a dted map. I read that gdal can read this kind of map. I didn't find a tutorial. I read about gdal [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) but it's not very "user-friendly". Can you give me any code snippet (only an hint) to read a single value of a dted map?

Comment: This is trivial with GIS software, and pretty easy from 'C' (with the the MIL-STD), but requiring GDAL seems to make the problem harder.

Comment: If you can point me a simple snippet of C code it's ok for me. Gdal is not needed actually but the library I found on Google about the dted reading without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: gdallocationinfo will work:

http://gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html

you can use it and the -geo option to output xml, or read the code for the application.

Answer (score 2):

I have written GDAL programs using C++ and C#. It is incredibly easy to use.

I advise you to download the source code. You'll find the source for gdallocationinfo, which is their command-line tool that does exactly what you want. You can use it as the lever to get going.

If using gdallocationinfo on the command line won't work for you.

-reilly.